# Opencv Read Mat with double precision YAML

Tags: opencv, yaml

I am trying to read data from a YAML file using the tutorials available at the OpenCV website. I am using the ">>" operator as suggested.

```
cv::Mat R;
cv::FileStorage fs;
fs.open(filename, cv::FileStorage::READ);
R >> fs["matrix"];
```

It basically works but I want the matrix to be in double precision not in float precision. Typing the matrix R as a double matrix does not do the job. What would be the right way to achieve this.

Comment: The data within the yaml file is in double precision. If I am changing the above code like that: cv::Mat R = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_64F); and read the data R >> fs["matrix"]; the matrix will be of float type.

Comment: No, it's not. Open the yml file and check the field "type". What number is that?

Comment: You are right. I did not know that the data is typed in the file I am loading. Thank you very much.

Comment: The field I was referring to was "dt". You probably have a "f" in that. Have a look at updated answer

Comment: Exactly, the matrix is typed as "dt: f". I got confused by the fact that the numbers I read in differ from the numbers in the file and I was not aware of the information within the file. Unfortunately I can not mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: You'll be able in [15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the image as *"double precision"*, aka of type `CV_64F`, the image need to be also stored as `CV_64F`.

If the image is saved as *"single precision"*, aka of type `CV_32F`, you can however load it as `CV_32F`, and then convert to `CV_64F` with:

```
R.convertTo(R, CV_64F);
```

You can check the format of the saved matrix opening the yml file, and checking the field `dt`. For `CV_32F` formats it will have a `f` in it, for `CV_64F` formats it will have a `d`.